# whole function automatically runs

Tags: javascript

In my Code my whole function is runing once means their is no break point. the program run like this that when i give value in 1st text box it will gives me 0 in all text boxes which i have made.Please tell me what i do.My coding is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Puchase Recipt</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function recipt()
{
var a = Number(document.f1.amount.value);
var b = Number(document.f1.quantity.value);
var pro = a*b;
if (pro > 100)
{
    var c = Number(document.f1.discount.value);
    var per = Number(pro * c / 100);
    var d = Number(document.f1.subtract.value);
    document.f1.subtract.value = per;
    }
var e = Number(document.f1.total.value);
var total = pro - per;
document.f1.total.value = total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Purchase Recipt</h1>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#000099">
<form name="f1">
<tr>
<th>Amount per KG</th>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Amount" name="amount" onChange="recipt()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Quntity of item</th>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" onChange="recipt()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Discount in %</th>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Discount" name="discount" onChange="recipt()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Deduct Amount</th>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Deduct Amount" name="subtract" onChange="recipt()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Total Amount</th>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Total Amount" name="total" onChange="recipt()"/></td>
</tr>
<th>Reset</th>
<td><input type="reset"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try to explain better what your problem is. I understand that English might not be your first language (neither is it mine), but it is not clear what exactly you are having troubles with.

Comment: If the problem is that you can't debug, try using firefox and firebug, there you can select the script file and set breakpoints.

Comment: Sir Felix KLing: if you don't mind please try this code yourself hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: if pro value is less than 100, what will be the value for pre?

Comment: For future reference, http://jsfiddle.net/ is a great tool to create demos for your code. This makes it easier for others to help you. I created one for you this time: http://jsfiddle.net/gJGeP/. That being said, is your problem that the total amount shows `NaN`? That's because `per` is not defined if `pro < 100`.

Comment: Sir Felix Kling: Thanks Sir Thank for helping.

Comment: Sie Nagaraj:Sir I will define per value then i will tell you thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code in javascript..

```
function recipt()
{
var a = Number(document.f1.amount.value);
var b = Number(document.f1.quantity.value);
var pro = a*b;
var per=0;
if (pro > 100)
{
    var c = Number(document.f1.discount.value);
    per = Number(pro * c / 100);
    var d = Number(document.f1.subtract.value);
    document.f1.subtract.value = per;
    }
var e = Number(document.f1.total.value);
var total = pro - per;
document.f1.total.value = total;
}
```

Comment: Sir now NaN is not comming but the problem is i want that when i give value of first and second text box it will multiply and not print any zero in any text box.

Comment: yes Nagaraj i want this Thanks and one more thing if pro is less than 100 alert box open can you tell me how i will do this.

Comment: Thanks my problem is solve.If you dont mind can you tell me what is the main purpose of using jsfiddle.net and how it works.

Comment: Refer these links http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html and http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/... In this tool you can run and test your Javascript, html, css code....,

Answer (score 0):

The things that you should correct first.

1. You should not call that `recipt` function on every input's change
   event. Rather you should call in that textbox's change event which
   is expected to be the last to be filled or a better way is to give a
   button for it and call the function on button's click.
2. First make validation whether the text boxes are empty before doing
   any calculations.If they are not empty check that the text boxes do
   not contain any non-numeric data otherwise your calculations will
   fail.

Try doing this and some little work will solve your problem